# Python: simple iteration of lists in a dict

Tags: python

I have this simple structure:

```
o = {
    2: [0, 148, 149, 150, 151],
    3: [0, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156],
    4: [0, 157, 158, 159, 160],
    5: [0, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166]
}
```

...and I am going nuts trying to isolate each number in the lists (eg. 0, 148, 149)

if I do any kind of loop I get:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What do I need to do?

Thanks!

BTW Python 2.6

Comment: I have improved the formatting. BTW, can you show your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for-loop iterates over keys which you can then use to lookup the corresponding sequences:

```
>>> o = {
    2: [0, 148, 149, 150, 151],
    3: [0, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156],
    4: [0, 157, 158, 159, 160],
    5: [0, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166]
}
>>> for key in o:
        seq = o[key]
        print key
        print seq
        print


2
[0, 148, 149, 150, 151]

3
[0, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156]

4
[0, 157, 158, 159, 160]

5
[0, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166]
```

Answer (score 3):

Next time, please show the code that fails.

I'm going to guess you do something like:

```
for x in o:
   for y in x:
       print y
```

The problem is that if you iterate over o, you get the keys not the values. What you want is:

```
   for key, value in o.items():
       for v in value:
           print v
```

Items returns a list of the keys and values as tuples and you can iterate over that.

Comment: I didnt show the code as I assumed an experienced python programmer would be able to formulate some simple code based on the dict structure. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @khany, showing code is important for two reasons. Firstly, it helps us correct whatever misunderstanding is preventing you from figuring it on your own. Secondly, it shows that you are actually trying. Sadly, many people seem to ask questions without trying to figure it out themselves and thus never manage to learn anything.